# Facebook python api documentation on all commands

Tags: python, facebook, api

I am using the facebook api but currently their code only teaches how to get your friends. I played with the graph api tool on their site and now I know what I need to extract, but is there a document out there that tells you all the commands for:

- gettings posts are there from a user
- how many likes a user's/company's page has
- what is the talking_about_count
- all posts that have a user's name tagged

this is all I have so far:

```
import facebook

token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("travelguard")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]

print profile['talking_about_count']
print profile['likes']
print friends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, no one here seems to know anything on facebook or linkedin apis. I figured it out myself...

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI("CAAErZAZAHDByABAHtXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
graph.get('me/posts')

#if you want to get someone else's post: graph.get('{id}/posts')
```